# Spring Boot external configuration on another server

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-boot

We are migrating applications to spring boot and we came to conclusion that it would be good to shift all configuration file to external server. I wonder if spring boot is capable of reading configuration file from another server during startup? If this is possible how can I achieve it? Now I read all config data from app-config.yml but in future I would like to get ride of this file from war. Thanks for any answers.

Comment: The configuration file does not have to be in the WAR. You can specify external file using `spring.config.location`, which can point for instance to `file:///srv/app/config.yml`. I have used this approach with configuration files stored on the same server, but in different directory than the project. It might be possible to reference some remote configuration file too, not sure. Take a look at [Externalized configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) for more details.

Comment: I know that this is possible from file but I want to get to know if this is also possible from external server.

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course spring has such stuff in the toolbox:

http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/

This would give you a central configuration server backed e.g. by a git repository holding the configuration.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can user Spring Cloud Config Server, it allows to share a properties folder via rest services.

In your application client include Spring Cloud Config Client dependency to property sources read those values from server.